# Oracle XMLTABLE and XPATH

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath, xmltable

I'm a bit lost with Xpath, I'm trying to get attributes from a XML, I'm currently using :

```
XMLTABLE('/attrs/attr[@name="ImagesWEB"]/string'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(XML)
    COLUMNS IMAGESWEB VARCHAR2(100) PATH '.'
)
```

But I need to get an other value with attribute name **Image2**, so I did an other XMLTABLE but I guess it's not the right way to do it, I have to use XMLTABLE('/attrs/attr'... with two columns, but don't know how can I get both (Image2 can be missing form the XML data) form XPATH ?

Here an XML example (coming for my product's CLOB) :

```
<attrs>
    <attr multiple="true" name="Image2">
        <string>IMG2.PNG</string>
        <string>IMG3.PNG</string>
        <string>IMG4</string>
    </attr>
    <attr multiple="true" name="ImagesWEB">
        <string>IMG.PNG</string>
    </attr>
    <attr name="ShortLink">
        <string>/PRODUCT.html</string>
    </attr>
    <attr name="TITRE">
        <string>TITLE</string>
    </attr>
    <attr name="name">
        <string>PRODUCT</string>
    </attr>
</attrs>

Thansk!
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your main XPath to just get the `attrs`, and then filter which you want in the Xpath for each `columns` clause:

```
XMLTABLE('/attrs'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(XML)
    COLUMNS
      IMAGESWEB VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'attr[@name="ImagesWEB"]/string',
      IMAGE2 VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'attr[@name="Image2"]/string'
)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1aef6ea39b03def3e99ec2bade24f5ea) with some made-up data.

---

> But what if I have two values (it might happen) ?

If you can have multiple `string` nodes under an attribute then you can get both `attr` nodes from one XMLTable call, and then have two more - one for each attr - to get the strings:

```
SELECT t.id, x2.imagesweb, x3.image2
FROM your_table t
CROSS APPLY
XMLTABLE('/attrs'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(t.XML)
    COLUMNS
      IMAGESWEB XMLTYPE PATH 'attr[@name="ImagesWEB"]',
      IMAGE2 XMLTYPE PATH 'attr[@name="Image2"]'
) x1
OUTER APPLY
XMLTABLE('/attr/string'
    PASSING x1.imagesweb
    COLUMNS
      IMAGESWEB VARCHAR2(100) PATH '.'
) x2
OUTER APPLY
XMLTABLE('/attr/string'
    PASSING x1.image2
    COLUMNS
      IMAGE2 VARCHAR2(100) PATH '.'
) x3
```

```
ID IMAGESWEB  IMAGE2
-- ---------  ----------
 1 ABC        DEF
 2 ABC
 3            DEF
 3            DEF2
 4 IMG.PNG    IMG2.PNG
 4 IMG.PNG    IMG3.PNG
 4 IMG.PNG    IMG4
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=edc700b77586886eff491e935717e5ec) with mix of made-up and sample data.

This uses cross apply and outer apply (because one or the other attribute might not exist), which are available [from Oracle 12c (12.1.0.1)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/release_changes.htm#sthref20).

Comment: Thanks it's working. But what if I have two values (it might happen) ?
Example : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c4f00d76cf1dcfb3412bb8067af0d2c7

Comment: That's why sample XML in the question is useful *8-) What would you expect the output to be in that case?

Comment: Thanks it looks like it's working for Oracle 18c, but error ORA-00900 on my Oracle  (12.1.0.2.0) and error ORA-00905 for Oracle 11g on dbfiddle

Comment: Works for me in 12.1.0.2. It won't work in 11g because cross/outer apply weren't added until 12gR1.

Comment: Very strange, it's working for one OUT APPLY only, if I use both I have ORA-00904 error.

Comment: Hmm, you might be hitting a bug, like [20356733](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=20356733.8), if you are on the base release - i.e. haven't a patchset update (to April 2016).